# SQL script that loops jobs for parallel execution

Tags: sql-server

I am working on process that will load data from ORACLE to SQL Server using the Attunity connector in SSIS. There are around 50 tables that I need to load and have created a job for each of them so that I can load them in parallel. Based on the server resources, I can run 10 at a time. I have a script that I have been working but it isn't working correctly because it fires 10 jobs and quits. I need the script to loop through the 50 jobs (start with PS_) and only run 10.

```html
DECLARE @a int
SET @a=0
DECLARE @jobname nvarchar(200)
-- checks if there are already 10 jobs running
WHILE ((@a <10) and (
   (SELECT count(*) FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs a 
   INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity b 
    ON a.job_id = B.job_id
   WHERE Start_Execution_date is not null 
   AND Stop_Execution_Date is null 
   AND substring (name, 1,3) = 'PS_')<= 10))
BEGIN
 SET @jobname = NULL
 --loops through to fetch one non-running job at a time and fetches upto 10 jobs 
 SELECT TOP 1 @jobName = name
 FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs X
 WHERE substring (x.name, 1,3) = 'PS_' 
 AND
 --checks the job did not already run today and is currently running.
 name IN (
   SELECT name FROM  msdb.dbo.sysjobs C 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (select max(start_execution_date) Start_Execution_date ,job_id  
       from msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity 
       group by job_id) B 
   ON B.job_id=C.Job_ID 
 where cast(isnull(Start_Execution_date,'01/01/1900') as date) < cast(getdate()as date))
 SELECT @jobname

 IF (@jobname is not null)
  BEGIN
   EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_Name=@jobName
   --select @jobname
  END
  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02'
  SET @a=@a+1
END
```

Comment: setup the jobs on a schedule, and stagger the start times?

Comment: Looks like you need an outer loop to keep repeating the inner loop until all 50 jobs have run, and change the loop control to < 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your while loop condition to check if there are any jobs that haven't run yet today.  Then query how many of your jobs are currently executing.  If more than 10 execute a waitfor delay; Otherwise, start the next job.  End loop.

Also you might want to add this to the where clause of your job queries.  I've been bit by this before.

```
WHERE a.session_id = (SELECT TOP 1 session_id FROM msdb.dbo.syssessions ORDER BY agent_start_date DESC)
```